# How to have "Post to Facebook" check-box cleared by default on fb:live-stream

Tags: facebook, controls, chat

The fb:live-stream control always sets "Post to Facebook" check-box by default and people are forgetting to clear it and then complaining of a spam by our app when they see their chat messages posted on the wall.  Is there a way to configure this control to start with unchecked check-box?

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Nopes, there is no way to turn that off.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't.  It's their goal to make users to post to Facebook ;)